# CodeIgniter pagination links not rendering

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

In my view, the links for pagination is not rendering.It was working earlier this day, don't know what I did wrong to make the generating of links fail.

```
public function index() {
    $data['user'] = $this->session->userdata();
    $_SESSION['nav'] = 1;
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $page = 2;
    $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'assigner/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->TasksModel->countPostedTasks();
    $config['per_page'] = $page;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = "</ul>";
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['tasks'] = $this->TasksModel->getPostedTasks($page, $offset);
    $this->load->view('assigner/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('assigner/index', $data);
}
```

Comment: I backtraced if the $links are loaded on to the view through print_r() function and it's not. Please help. Thanks

Comment: are you sure that there are data to show? (`$this->TasksModel->countPostedTasks()` != 0)

Comment: ` public function countPostedTasks(){
        $id = $this->session->userdata('assigner_id');
        $q = $this->db->get_where('tasks', array('task_status' => 1,'assigner_id' => $id));
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the number of links the pagination library should show.
Add this line to your code.

```
$config['num_links'] = round($config['total_rows'] / $config['per_page']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
public function index() {
    $data['user'] = $this->session->userdata();
    $_SESSION['nav'] = 1;
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $per_page = 2;

    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'assigner/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->TasksModel->countPostedTasks();
    $config['per_page'] = $per_page;

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $offset = ($page == 0 ? 0 : ($page - 1) * $config["per_page"]);

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['tasks'] = $this->TasksModel->getPostedTasks($page, $offset);

    $data['total_page'] = ceil($config['total_rows'] / $config['per_page']);

    $this->load->view('assigner/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('assigner/index', $data);
}
```